# Adding a new line to the end of a file using sed

Tags: macos, sed

I need to add a new line to the end of a file. But when I am running sed command on MacOS I get an error.

The command I run
`sed -i'' -e '$a\wrapper{gradleVersion='5.5'}' build.gradle`

The error I get: 
`sed: 1: "$a\wrapper{gradleVersio ...": extra characters after \ at the end of a command`

Comment: your version of `sed` doesn't like `a` data on the same line. you'll have to add a CR after the "\" char and probably add a blank line after the closing `}'`. Note also that if you're expecting to have `'5.5'` appear (with the single quotes), you'll need to use dbl=quotes to wrap your `-e` command, i.e. `"$a\....'5.5'}"`. Good luck.

Comment: why don't you simply use : `echo "wrapper{gradleVersion='5.5'}" >> build.gradle` ??

Comment: Questions like this further convince me that the root of all evil is *not* the love of money.  It is the `-i` option of gnu sed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest answer : do not use `sed`

```
echo "wrapper{gradleVersion='5.5'}" >> build.gradle
```

Pretty straightforward right ?

If you want to ignore my advices and keep using `sed`, to complete @shellter comment :

- On MacOS sed, you need to add newlines before the text you want to add when using `a` command.
- MacOS sed will not add a newline by default after the text you want to add, and because you want the file remains POSIX standard, you'll need to add it

You can do :

```
sed -i '' -e '$a\
<text to add>
' <file>
```

- Because you want to add single quotes, you need to wrap sed command with double quotes, then escape `$` and `\` which make it particularly annoying to use.

Try this :

```
sed -i '' "\$a\\
wrapper{gradleVersion='5.5'}
" build.gradle
```

On gnu-sed (install it with [brew](https://brew.sh/index_fr) `brew install gnu-sed`), you would do :

```
gsed -i "\$a wrapper{gradleVersion='5.5'}" build.gradle
```

Comment: Using multiple `-e` to create effective newlines might also work `sed -e '$a\' -e 'wrapper{gradleVersion='5.5'}'`  More than one line requires a backslash continuation for each non-end line.

Comment: @stevesliva interesting solution but it didn't work on my MacOS sed version.

Comment: (it does not add anything)